# Highlighting a single character in ace

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to highlight a single character (at a given position) in an ace editor. It seems that I can use `addMarker` for this, but documentation is pretty much non-existant and I can't make sense of what is going on in my attempts.

Here is one quick demo attempt ([<kbd>fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vvpxh7zk/)):

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (currentMarker) {
        editor.session.removeMarker(currentMarker);
    }

    currentMarker = editor.session.addMarker(new Range(1, x, 2, x+1), "marked", "text", false);

    x = ++x % 25;
}, 250);
```

I would *expect* a single character to be highlighted and every quarter second the marker should switch to the character next to it. But that's not what happens.

My questions here would be
* Why does it behave this way?
* How do I make it behave the way I want to?
* I read about "dynamic" markers, but can't find any information on what those are. So – what are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `position: absolute;` for marked class and to use same row for start and end of the range `new Range(1, x, 1, x+1)`

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;

var currentMarker;
var x = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (currentMarker)
        editor.session.removeMarker(currentMarker);

    currentMarker = editor.session.addMarker(new Range(1, x, 1, x+1), "marked", "text", false);
    x = ++x % 25;
}, 250);
```

```css
#editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.marked {
    background: red;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }
function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }
function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }</div>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.1.7/min/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```